# How do I find user login history?

Tags: security, users

So, I need to know when my account in ubuntu is accessed. Is there any command that will show me the **Exact Time** when that happened.
I need this because I suspect someone is remotely controlling my computer, and changing things.

Answer (score 8):

## `last` command to the rescue

The `last` command shows by a given user name or all user names:

```
$ last rick
rick     tty7         :0               Wed Apr 24 16:25    gone - no logout
rick     tty8         :1               Wed Apr 24 16:24 - down   (00:00)
rick     tty7         :0               Tue Apr 23 20:12 - down   (20:06)
rick     tty7         :0               Tue Apr 23 18:30 - crash  (01:42)
  (...SNIP...)
rick     tty7         :0               Tue Apr  2 16:52 - down   (00:31)
rick     tty7         :0               Tue Apr  2 03:14 - crash  (13:37)
```

By default it only shows history for the current month. If you need to go further back in history than one month, you can read the `/var/log/wtmp.1` file with the `last` command.

`last -f wtmp.1 rick` will show the previous month's history of logins for user `rick`:

```
$ last -f /var/log/wtmp.1 rick
rick     tty7         :0               Sun Mar 31 16:53    gone - no logout
rick     tty7         :0               Sat Mar 30 19:18 - down   (13:20)
  (...SNIP...)
rick     tty7         :0               Fri Mar  1 20:55 - down   (11:55)

wtmp.1 begins Fri Mar  1 18:23:28 2019
```

Security is hardened such that normal users can't write or delete the file:

```
$ ll /var/log/wtmp.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 107520 Mar 31 16:53 /var/log/wtmp.1
```

## Console only logins

The console uses the `login` command which records data to `/var/log/lastlog`:

```
$ ll /var/log/lastlog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 292292 Apr 24 16:22 /var/log/lastlog
```

The `lastlog` file though cannot be tampered with so easily when you look at the File Owner and File Group above. "Normal" users just have read access. It's a binary file though so you can't just `cat` it and get meaningful information. Use this command instead:

```
$ lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root                                       **Never logged in**
daemon                                     **Never logged in**
bin                                        **Never logged in**
sys                                        **Never logged in**
  (...SNIP...)
usbmux                                     **Never logged in**
rick             tty1                      Wed Nov 28 04:19:53 -0700 2018
vnstat                                     **Never logged in**
```

It's interesting to see all the different user IDs that could log in but never have and never should. I was surprised I haven't logged into the console / terminal since November last year.

Answer (score 4):

This would be shown in `/var/log/auth.log` if the 'person' controlling your system remotely is not smart enough to clean up the logs.  You might be able to see login data by using:

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep USERNAME
```

(where `USERNAME` is your user).

Beyond this, however, if there's nothing in this log, and you *really* do think you're being remote-controlled, I'd suggest clean-installing your system and starting from scratch with different passwords and better hardening your system.